# Why was my question about an IDE issue closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question *[Indexing freeze with message: Indexing paused due to batch updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513097/indexing-freeze-with-message-indexing-paused-due-to-batch-updated/52516311)* is about the problem associated with an IDE. I cannot give any sample code or anything else. Why was it closed as unclear?

What there can be unclear? What else can I add to improve the question?

Comment: Since you are new to meta, please do not worry about potential down-votes here. They will not affect your account or reputation, and are used much more liberally in meta to do things like signal disagreement with a question's premise, besides their usual meanings.

Comment: I am puzzle by the sentence "Illegal closing" At the bottom of every page and at the creation of an account there is a link to [licensing](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and the [term of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public).

Comment: Hmm, could it be because OP's native language isn't English? @xdtTransform

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've updated Android Studio to version 3.2.
>
> After that update one of my projects don't want to index.
>
> It freezes with the message
>
> > "Indexing paused due to batch updated".
>
> How can I fix this?

There obviously seems more detailed information missing from your question. It is probably not useful for future research.

May be add more specific information about your project structure and dependencies.

There's nothing *illegal* with the close reason though.

Comment: What kind of information I can add if the issue happened by his own. The project was working project. And after update studio it wan't to index.

Comment: @AxborAxrorov Well, I've enhanced my answer a bit.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to add some information about gradle settings

Comment: @AxborAxrorov Good idea.

Answer (score 9):

The [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52513097/1) of your question which looked like this,

> [image]

was used as a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21022578) and reported by a user to be a poorly-chosen audit in the **Reopen Votes review queue**<sup>#</sup>. Review audits for this queue are system-picked, based on a certain number of votes.

Luckily the user found out that this review was an audit and selected the incorrect "correct answer" to "Reopen". Other users who might encounter this question would very likely have selected "Leave Closed" as the question was poorly asked (did not contain sufficient information to investigate/reproduce the error), and therefore unfairly failed the review audit, which would contribute towards a review ban.

To mitigate this issue, the known methods to bump this post off the review audit list are:

- applying downvotes (until the question is zero or negatively-scored), or
- voting to **close**, or
- voting to delete

I chose the least destructive method, voting to close, to immediately remediate the issue and hopefully get you to provide further details in your question.

---

<sup>#</sup> Review queues are available at 500 reputation. For more information about reviews, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/165483

Comment: *applying downvotes (until the question is zero or negatively-scored* I thought having at least one up and down vote was enough to prevent it from being used as an audit. My understanding was that only posts where there was a consensus (all up votes or all down votes) were eligible.

Comment: @BSMP I might be wrong on this point, so just answering based on what I know will *definitely* work.

Comment: Judging from experience and the 130-some upvotes, it seems like all it takes is Android Studio 3+, a project that used to build, waiting and some luck to reproduce this problem. The details he added almost seem like a red herring, unless you'd like everyone else to re-ask this question with their own settings details listed, which I expect is not wanted.